# Integrate bootstrap and fuel ux references

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fuelux

I already have a web application where I have used the twitter bootstrap library. Now I want to use some widgets from Fuel UX library and I am unable to mix both bootstrap widget as well as Fuel UX widget in same page. The only possible way currently is to replace all bootstrap references with Fuel UX referneces but then it makes a big change in my web app and I don't want to spend time making all the UI fixes. Hence, is there any way I can use both the libraries?

I am using jquery 1.9.0, bootstrap 3.0 and fuel ux 2.3